# utf-8 search for word in list

Tags: python, search, utf-8

I have a lookup list generated from utf-8 file by

```
with open('stop_word_Tiba.txt') as f:
    newStopWords= list(itertools.chain( line.split() for line in f)) #save the file as list of lines
newStopWords1d=list(itertools.chain(*newStopWords)) # convert 2d list to 1d list
```

when I open the file I see that the word 'الو' is in there. so it is in the list, but the list now looks like 
['\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x88', '\xd8\xa3\xd9\x84\xd9\x88', '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd9\x83\xd9\x8a', '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84', '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x87', '\xd8\xa3\xd9\x87', '\xd9\x87\xd9\x84\xd9\x88', '\xd8\xa3\xd9\x88\xd9\x83\xd9\x8a', '\xd9\x88']

Then I would like to search if a specific word is in newStopWords1d
the word 'الو' is '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x88'

```
word='الو'
for w in newStopWords1d:
    if word == w.encode("utf-8"):
        print 'found'
```

The word is not found, I tried

```
    if word in newStopWords1d:
        print 'found'
```

but again the word is not seen. It seems like the problem with encoding but I couldn't solve it. can you please help me.

Comment: Did you write this file yourself, by writing `str(my_list)`? If so, can you throw the file away and write a file in a more useful format, like JSON, or just one string per line?

Comment: If you're stuck with this file as-is, you probably want to use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the input back to a list of strings, and then search through the list of strings instead of searching through the string representation of the list of strings. But, again, if it's at all possible to rewrite the file properly, do that instead.

Comment: in python2.7, removing `.encode("utf-8")`, and using only `if word == w:` produces `found`

Comment: OK yes that is also a solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worth mentioning was that you use Python 2.7.

```
word='الو'
for w in newStopWords1d:
    if word == w.decode("utf-8"):
        print 'found'
```

Even better solution is to use either the open function from [`io`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open)

```
import io

with io.open('stop_word_Tiba.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    ...
```

or [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) module

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('stop_word_Tiba.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    ...
```

as the built-in open function in Python 2.7 doesn't support specifying the encoding.

Comment: yes  correct Python 2.7, and the problem was with opining the file as utf-8. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by editing the open file statement as

```
with codecs.open("stop_word_Tiba.txt", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    newStopWords= list(itertools.chain( line.split() for line in f)) #save the file as list of lines
newStopWords1d=list(itertools.chain(*newStopWords))
    for w in newStopWords1d:
            if word.encode("utf-8") == w.encode("utf-8") :  
                      return 'found'
```

Thanks for you..

Comment: I believe `if word.encode("utf-8") == w` would be enough. `w` is already `utf-8` encoded

Comment: Actually no need for both if the file was opened as utf-8, I tested the run with out both i.e. if word == w : return 'found'  and it found the word. Thanks